# Docker Desktop kubernetes cluster reports Authentication required when pulling images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

Deploying a manifest in Docker Desktop (v4.21.1) Kubernetes cluster.

The image used in manifest looks like below,

```
my-local.artifactory.com/docker-images/my-app:v1.0.0
```

The secret with docker config is created and referred within the manifest in  `imagePullSecrets`. The `imagePullPolicy` is set to `Always`.

Error message

```
Failed to pull image "my-local.artifactory.com/docker-images/my-app:v1.0.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head "https://my-local.artifactory.com/v2/docker-images/my-app/manifests/v1.0.0": unknown: Authentication is required
```

The deployment failed since not able to pull image and indicates **Authentication required**. Odd thing is that the `kubelet docker-desktop` used the URL that looks like - `https://my-local.artifactory.com/v2/myapp/manifests/v1.0.0`

But not sure how this URL is constructed.

- Question:
  How Docker desktop kubelet know to create this url `https://my-local.artifactory.com/v2/myapp/manifests/v1.0.0`? Not sure how `v2` is added to the URL.

When hit the URL directly in browser, do get below message.

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

Comment: which Kubernetes you are using? is it on prem or cloud?YOu installed JFrog Artifactory with helm?

Comment: v2 the the api version. If has nothing to do with your image/tag

Comment: Can you do a `docker login my-local.artifactory.com` with the username/password used in the secret? How did you create your secret?

Comment: was using local Kubernetes V1.27.2, configured to WSL2

Comment: The issue was in the Yaml manfiest code which I used to deploy. The deployment is done using Operator and in Custom resource manifest the`imagePullSecrets` configuration was placed under incorrect property. Totally a manifest related issue.

Answer (score 3):

The URL is specified by the [Docker Registry HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/).

The image name `my-local.artifactory.com/docker-images/my-app:v1.0.0` breaks down into three parts: the registry name `my-local-artifactory.com`, the image name `docker-images/my-app`, and the tag `v1.0.0`.  To [pull the image](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image), the kubelet (or anything else) first needs to fetch a piece called the *image manifest*, and that manifest has a list of the individual *layers* that need to be downloaded.

The registry API specifies the manifest URL as

```
GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
```

where `GET` is an HTTP verb, `<name>` is the image name, and `<reference>` is either the tag or a digest hash.  This matches the URL in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris mentioned, v2 in the URL represents  the api version.

From your description we know that you are using an artifact registry for storing your images.

The  error  describes that it requires authentication to access this image/artifact

As per this [article](https://support.count.ly/hc/en-us/articles/4698120212889-Docker-and-Kubernetes-Connecting-to-Private-Artifact-Registry-and-Pulling-Images-with-Authentication-Plugin-Packages) in County:

> **Authenticating and Pulling Images from Artifact Registry**
>
> Kubernetes uses Secrets to authenticate or store the credentials to
> access a Docker registry for images.
>
> **Follow below steps  to create a Kubernetes Secret**.
>
> 1.To fetch service account email from service account key:
>
> ```
> cat serviceaccount.json | grep client_email  # Value used in docker-email key
> ```
>
> 2.Create a Kubernetes Secret:
>
> ```
> kubectl create secret docker-registry artifact-registry \
> --docker-server=https://us-docker.pkg.dev \
> --docker-email=<service account email address> \
> --docker-username=_json_key \
> --docker-password="$(cat serviceaccount.json)"
> ```
>
> 3.Verify the creation of Kubernetes Secret:
>
> ```
> kubectl get secrets | grep artifact-registry
> ```
>
> Once you  have obtained the Service Account key, then you  can
> authenticate to Artifact Registry using the command below:
>
> ```
> cat serviceaccount.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://us-docker.pkg.dev
> ```

Comment: This is correct, the `imagePullSecrets` of Docker configure was placed incorrectly in the Custom Resource manifest that I deployed. With `helm template` the yaml file generated clearly indicated it.